# Redshift - Find % as compared to total value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with count by product. I am trying to add a new column that would find % as compared to sum of all rows in that column.

```
prod_name,count
prod_a,100
prod_b,50
prod_c,150
```

For example, I want to find % of prod_a as compared to the total count and so on.

Expected output:

```
prod_name,count,%
prod_a,100,0.33
prod_b,50,0.167
prod_c,150,0.5
```

Edit on SQL:

```
select count(*),ratio_to_report(prod_name)
over (partition by count(*)) 
from sales
group by prod_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using window functions.

```
select t.*,100.0*cnt_by_prod/sum(cnt_by_prod) over() as pct
from tbl t
```

Edit: Based on OP's question change, To compute the counts and then percentage, use

```
select prod_name,100.0*count(*)/sum(count(*)) over()
from tbl
group by prod_name
```

Comment: I have edited my post with the SQL I am using to group count by prod_id. Could you please help me tweak this to find % as compared against total. Thanks